# Send by e-mail SSRS report using SSIS package scheduled in SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, email, reporting-services, ssis

I have a SSIS package that export SSRS report (report have parameters) in excel and have stored it on disk. Then I can e-mail it. But, I need to e-mail SSRS report using SSIS package without storing it on disc. Also, e-mail addresses have to be from data base table, which will be filtered by field in the table "address type" (main address, region address etc.) that will  depend from choosen parameters in report. 
My goal for today is to send stored file by E-mail at least to one recipient. So, here is ScriptTask that I use to send file that I have stored on disc from SSRS with the help of one more Script task in created SSIS Package. Script give next error "", and also error arises if I uncomment string 'objmes.AddAttachment = "e:\report.xls"

```
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum


    Public Sub Main()
        Dim objmes
        objmes = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        objmes.From = "e-mail1"
        objmes.To = "e-mail2"
        objmes.Subject = "my first E-mail"
        objmes.TextBody = "Hello world"
        'objmes.AddAttachment = "e:\report.xls"
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.*****.com"
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "email1"
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "*******"
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
        objmes.Configuration.Fields.Update()
        objmes.Send()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail or [perhaps this would help](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/08/sending-mail-within-ssis-part-3-execute.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I have read about and it did not help me to solve my problem

Comment: You mentioned that there is a problem, however, you didn't explain that problem, what you've already tried or what error you're running into. Please explain in greater depth so others can help better.

Comment: The main trouble is that I can't invent how attach report fom SSRS to email without storing it on disk

Answer (score 0):

For your second question that you want to get the email based on the address type

It would be something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mail_generation]

-- the input parameters
@addresstypekey as uniqueidentifier

AS
BEGIN
declare @email nvarchar(120)

declare crs cursor for 
select c.email
from  contacts c inner join addresstype ad on c.addresstypekey = ad.addresstypekey
where ad.addresstypekey = @addresstypekey

open crs
fetch next from crs into @email

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @email

   fetch next from crs into @email

end

close crs 
deallocate crs

END
```

So you have an input parameter which is the address type (main address, region address etc.)

select emails of the specified type

then send mail to each of the recipients have this type of address.

Comment: Thanks everybody who was trying to help me, but I have already solved my problem using C# instead of VB Script.